# Downgrade GLSL Fragment Shader to lowest version possible (at least GLSL 3.3)

Tags: c#, glsl, shader, fragment-shader, opentk

Good day for everyone.

I trying to make Node Based Editor, for specific purpose. So i borrowed ortographic grid style, used by Unreal Engine 4 Blueprint Editor, for a start. And write simple fragment shader for this. Because i dont really need any vertex information from grid, it just drawn at center point, that i move by right mouse button and pass it, into shader. How can i downgrade that shader to lowest version possible, for compatibility reasons, at least to GLSL 3.3? I use C# and OpenTK for this.

Help please. I will be glad for any advice on how to make this shader more efficient.

**Drawing quad for grid and using shader:**

```
GL.UseProgram(BasicProgramID);
GL.Uniform1(0, 16); //x cell size
GL.Uniform1(1, 16); //y cell size
// center point that controlled by mouse, invert y - axis, because shader draw from left bottom, idk why=(
GL.Uniform2(2, CenterPos.X , glControl1.Height - CenterPos.Y); 

//prevent screen quad to move by other transformations
GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview); 
GL.PushMatrix();
GL.LoadIdentity();

GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads); //sorry for that deprecated method=) that's simplier to test app 
     GL.Color3(0, 0, 0);
     GL.Vertex2(0.0f, 0.0f);
     GL.Vertex2(glControl1.Width, 0.0f);
     GL.Vertex2(glControl1.Width, glControl1.Height);
     GL.Vertex2(0.0f, glControl1.Height);
GL.End();
GL.PopMatrix();

GL.UseProgram(0);
```

**Grid Fragment Shader:**

```
#version 430

layout(location = 0) uniform int grid_dx;
layout(location = 1) uniform int grid_dy;
layout(location = 2) uniform vec2 grid_center;

out vec4 frag_color;

vec4 CenterAxisColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 BackgroundColor = vec4(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1.0);
vec4 InnerLinesColor = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
vec4 SectionBorderColor = vec4(0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.15); 

void main() {  
    if ((int(gl_FragCoord.x) == int(grid_center.x))||(int(gl_FragCoord.y) == int(grid_center.y)))
        frag_color = CenterAxisColor;
    else if((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % (grid_dx * 8) == 0)||(int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % (grid_dy * 8) == 0))
        frag_color = SectionBorderColor;
    else if ((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % grid_dx == 0)||(int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % grid_dy == 0))
        frag_color = InnerLinesColor;
    else 
        frag_color = BackgroundColor;
}
```

**UPDATE**

In previous shader version, have been many mistakes and no way to use zoom and customization. So i've decided to put final version with comments here.

```
#version 150

// Shader creates orthorgaphic grid like in Unreal Engine 4 Blueprint Editor.
// You can change parameters to create custom look and don't have problems with copyright.
// I dont provide lines thickness, because I would have to use a more cumbersome method for rendering.
// Even with one pixel size it works very accurate, because of straight lines and integer coordinates.
// You can do with that code what you want. I hope this helps someone. 

 // set top-left origin for window coordinates and moves the (x, y) value returned by gl_FragCoord of (0.5, 0.5) by default, to (0.0, 0.0)
layout (origin_upper_left, pixel_center_integer) in vec4 gl_FragCoord;

 // out pixel color. Set current pixel color for every shader call.
out vec4 frag_color;

// position of grid center. Used to pan grid. Just pass mouse position, when right mouse button pressed, for example.
uniform vec2 grid_center; 

// smallest cell size. Used to set grid zoom. By default in UE4 16px, with zoom changes to 14, 12, 10 etc.
uniform ivec2 cell_size = ivec2(16, 16); 

// you can also pass parameters in shader presented below just add "uniform"

// count of cells in section.
ivec2 cell_count = ivec2(8, 8); 

// all colors. By default like in UE4 Blueprint Editor
vec4 BackgroundColor = vec4(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1.0);
vec4 CenterAxisColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 InnerLinesColor = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
vec4 SectionBorderColor = vec4(0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.15); 

void main() {  
    frag_color = BackgroundColor; // set back color first and check other situations

    // check if that grid center?
    if ((gl_FragCoord.x == grid_center.x)||(gl_FragCoord.y == grid_center.y)) 
    {
         frag_color = CenterAxisColor;
    } 
    else 
    {
        //upper-right sections
        if ((gl_FragCoord.x >= grid_center.x) && (gl_FragCoord.y <= grid_center.y)) // that pixel in correct part, relative to the center?
            if(((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % (cell_size.x * cell_count.x)) == 0)|| ((int(grid_center.y - gl_FragCoord.y) % (cell_size.y * cell_count.y)) == 0)) // that pixel lay on section border?
                frag_color = SectionBorderColor;
            else if(((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % cell_size.x) == 0)|| ((int(grid_center.y - gl_FragCoord.y) % cell_size.y) == 0)) // that pixel lay on section divider-line?
                    frag_color = InnerLinesColor;

        //bottom-right sections
        if ((gl_FragCoord.x >= grid_center.x) && (gl_FragCoord.y >= grid_center.y)) // etc...
            if(((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % (cell_size.x * cell_count.x)) == 0)|| ((int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % (cell_size.y * cell_count.y)) == 0)) 
                frag_color = SectionBorderColor;
            else if(((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % cell_size.x) == 0)|| ((int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % cell_size.y) == 0)) 
                    frag_color = InnerLinesColor;

        //bottom-left sections
        if ((gl_FragCoord.x <= grid_center.x) && (gl_FragCoord.y >= grid_center.y))
            if(((int(grid_center.x - gl_FragCoord.x) % (cell_size.x * cell_count.x)) == 0)|| ((int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % (cell_size.y * cell_count.y)) == 0)) 
                frag_color = SectionBorderColor;
            else if(((int(grid_center.x - gl_FragCoord.x) % cell_size.x) == 0)|| ((int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % cell_size.y) == 0)) 
                    frag_color = InnerLinesColor;

        //upper-left sections
        if ((gl_FragCoord.x <= grid_center.x) && (gl_FragCoord.y <= grid_center.y))
            if(((int(grid_center.x - gl_FragCoord.x) % (cell_size.x * cell_count.x)) == 0)|| ((int(grid_center.y - gl_FragCoord.y) % (cell_size.y * cell_count.y)) == 0)) 
                frag_color = SectionBorderColor;
            else if(((int(grid_center.x - gl_FragCoord.x) % cell_size.x) == 0)|| ((int(grid_center.y - gl_FragCoord.y) % cell_size.y) == 0)) 
                    frag_color = InnerLinesColor;
    }
}
```

[Shader work screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM5qE.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `GL.Begin`/`Gl.End` sequences, then you have to use a [GLSL 1.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf) vertex shader and the [built in Vertex Attributes](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/tutorials/ClockworkCoders/attributes.php) `gl_Vertex`, `gl_Normal`, `gl_Color` and `gl_MultiTexCoord0`.

---

Anyway [OpenGL Shading Language 3.30](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf) does not support location [Layout Qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) for uniform variables (except by enabling the extension [`GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_explicit_uniform_location.txt)).

You have to remove the layout location (<s>`layout(location = 0)`</s>). Get the location of the uniform variable by [`GL.GetUniformLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/opentk.graphics.es20.gl.getuniformlocation?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) after the program is linked.

```c
#version 330

uniform int grid_dx;
uniform int grid_dy;
uniform vec2 grid_center;

out vec4 frag_color;

vec4 CenterAxisColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
vec4 BackgroundColor = vec4(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 1.0);
vec4 InnerLinesColor = vec4(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1.0);
vec4 SectionBorderColor = vec4(0.09, 0.09, 0.09, 0.15); 

void main() {  
    if ((int(gl_FragCoord.x) == int(grid_center.x))||(int(gl_FragCoord.y) == int(grid_center.y)))
        frag_color = CenterAxisColor;
    else if((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % (grid_dx * 8) == 0)||(int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % (grid_dy * 8) == 0))
        frag_color = SectionBorderColor;
    else if ((int(gl_FragCoord.x - grid_center.x) % grid_dx == 0)||(int(gl_FragCoord.y - grid_center.y) % grid_dy == 0))
        frag_color = InnerLinesColor;
    else 
        frag_color = BackgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: Good news. Now shader works even with "#version 150". Because "OpenGL Shading Language 3.30" signs: No features were removed or deprecated between versions 1.50 and 3.30." Thanks for useful links.